# How do I relocate a big MySQL database from one server to another?

Tags: mysql, linux, database, phpmyadmin, cpanel

Hy people, hope you all are doing great. I am doing servers relocation. I have a website with big database (8GB). Now I can't just download the entire database from phpmyadmin and then do the import on new server (That will be time consuming and I don't have that fast internet). However my server does have a fast internet so I was thinking if I could do the migration using server's resources. Is there anyone who has done it before? How do I do it? I know Linux. I would be very thankful to you if you could help me in any way.

Comment: You can use `mysqldump` to export your database, `scp` it to your new server and import it using the `mysql` command from there. If you need help doing that, may I suggest the [unix/linux community](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: thanks @rickdenhaan

Comment: You're going to need shell access to both Linux systems to do this without really strange contortions.  `mysqldump`,`gzip`, `split` and `scp` are your new best friends on the origin server. `cat`, `gunzip`, and the `mysql` command line client are your friends on the destination server.

Comment: i got it @O.Jones thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

you can use SSh to export DB with mysqldump

```
mysqldump -u [USERNAME] -p [DBNAME] | gzip > [/path_to_file/DBNAME].sql.gz
```

then uplaod DB file to new server and launch this command

```
gzip [/path_to_file/DBNAME].sql.gz | mysql -u[USER] -p[PASS] [DBNAME]
```

Comment: If you want to backup also stored procedures, use -R